# SBCL Buildapp -- How to go about debugging/troubleshooting?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I have a SBCL program that works fine in the REPL (and I've successfully built it before), but after a few changes to the code, the build doesn't work anymore. It still successfully build, but running the binary gives me strange errors:

```
fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 940(tid 2953912320):
thread_state: os_sem_wait(0x1408000): 4, No such file or directory
```

It still works fine in the REPL (the binary is also in same folder)

What is the best way to debug this situation? So far, I've been just trying things and rebuilding -- is there a better way?

Comment: how do you create a binary? `save-lisp-and-die`?

Answer (score 0):

> The ASDF central registry is temporarily extended with the `--asdf-path` and `--asdf-tree`
>   arguments at load time, and reverts back to the default central registry value after that.
>   To avoid conflicts with this behavior, changes to the central registry should be done at
>   startup time instead of application load time.
>   [Buildapp. Implementation](http://www.xach.com/lisp/buildapp/#implementation)

So, if you use some `asdf` utility in runtime, it could cause such an error, I think.